# Log Shipping Alert

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, log

I have 3 databases which I have took them offline and I have Log Shipping setup on them and I wanted to stop alerts for those databases. How can I do that?

Thank You for help

Comment: You should first stop all jobs related to logshippping then remove logshipping and then take database offline. You can use SSMS as well to remove LS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189071.aspx

Comment: I also think it was not a difficult task to find. Please develop a habit to search it will benefit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete logshipping for the databases that you offlined. That will stop the alerts.

[How to: Remove Log Shipping (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191297.aspx)

> On the **primary server**, execute `sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_secondary` to delete the information about the secondary database from the primary server.
>
> On the **secondary server**, execute `sp_delete_log_shipping_secondary_database` to delete the secondary database.
>
> On the **primary server**, execute `sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_database` to delete information about the log shipping configuration from the primary server. This also deletes the backup job.
>
> Delete the secondary database from the secondary server if desired.